# Global function and method at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, I'm writing a function that uses two arrays. How can I define this function to call it as a global function, passing it two arrays or as an `Array` method, passing it a second array:

```
func([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]);
[1, 2, 3].func([3, 2, 1]);
```

Here is my idea:

```
func = function (...args) { // define global function
    if (args.length > 1) { 
        // function called as global with 2 arrays in arguments
    } else {
        // function called as Array method, with second array in arguments
    }
}
Array.prototype.func = func; // define Array method
```

Is there a more better way?
Thanks.

Comment: The number of arguments doesn't tell you how the function was called, given that you could have a call like `[1, 2, 3].func([3, 2, 1], [4, 5, 6])`. You could instead test whether `this` is an array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps create a wrapper function for the prototype:

```
func = function (a,b) { // define global function
    // will always have a,b defined
}
Array.prototype.func = function (b){ func(this,b) }; // define Array method
```

This way it doesnt make any difference for your function.
(Assuming your function expects exactly 2 arguments)